# Combine the ratios of two different vectors in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I don't know how to explain it so it if this question exists, just point me to the right topic. I have searched the forum but couldn't find any answer (maybe there is a keyword in mathematics or statistics for this that I am missing).

How do I produce a vector with combined weights from two vectors?

For example given two vectors:

```
vector_1 = {3, 3, 4}
vector_2 = {5, 5}
```

We calculate their weights which is the element divided by the sum of the elements in the vector.

```
weights_1 = {0.3, 0.3, 0.4}
weights_2 = {0.5, 0.5}
```

These are then combined to produce this vector. The combined weights is the combined ratios of the two vectors.

```
combined_weights = {0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4}
```

is there a function that can calculate the combined weights?

```
combined_weights = calculate(weights_1, weights_2)
```

The process is:

```
Step 1: combined_weights = {0.3}
```

0.3 is the first element of weights_1.

```
Step 2: combined_weights = {0.3, 0.2, 0.1}
```

The sum of 0.2 and 0.1 is the the second element of weights_1. The sum of the combined_weights vector is equal to the first element of weights_2.

```
Step 3: combined_weights = {0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4}
```

From the combined_weights vector we can get both weights_1 and weights_2, i.e.

```
    weights_1 = {0.3, 0.2 + 0.1, 0.4}
    weights_2 = {0.3 + 0.2, 0.1 + 0.4}
```

My goal is to make vector_1 and vector_2 have similar size.

```
new_vector_1 = {3, 2, 1, 4}
new_vector_2 = {3, 2, 1, 4}
```

[image]

More generally,

[image]

Comment: It seems `weights_1` and `weights_2` are simply `vector_1` and `vector_2` divided by ten, but I personally have no clue how you you from those to `combined_weights`, can you explain how exactly are each of those four values computed?

Comment: Could you provide an explanation of how ````weights_1```` and ````weights_2```` are calculated and then ````combined_wights```` ? It is not clear.

Comment: I might be dense but I don't get what you're trying to calculate at all... Are all vectors and weights independents before the computation? How do you end up with 4 elements from 3 and 5?

Comment: I suppose that: Be `n` the sum of values in the vector, `w_i = v_i/n`

Comment: I apologize, the weights are calculated as the value of each element in the vector divided by the sum of the elements in the vector.

Comment: @NikkiMino but what is the desired output? The second step is the same but with the `w_i` as input. I don't understand the last line

Comment: I updated my question. I apologize if it is very confusing. The desired output is the merging (not sure about this term) of the two weights. In the post above, I want to get the combined_weights.

Comment: @NikkiMino How do you merge the weights for your example? It is not clear what you mean by "combined ratios".

Comment: But how did you go from 3 and 2 elements, to 4 elements? How do you decide that? How do you calculate the combined weights?

Comment: @eike, I am not really sure what to call it.

Comment: Rather than giving an example,  try describing HOW - if you were doing the calculations on paper - you would obtain the elements of `combined_weights` given a list of elements in each of `weights_1` and `weights_2`.       If you don't describe the HOW, providing an example is meaningless.   If you *can't* describe the HOW, then nobody can help you - we're not mindreaders.

Comment: I have updated my question using a step-by-step procedure.

Comment: We still don't know where you get `0.2, 0.1` from. Why not `0.1, 0.2` or `0.15, 0.15` etc?

Comment: @Caleth, If we use 0.15, 0.15 we cannot get weights_2 from it only weights_1, i.e. weights_1 = {0.3,  0.15 + 0.15, 0.4} = {0.3, 0.3, 0.4} but weights_2 = {0.3 + 0.15, 0.15 + 0.4} = {0.45, 0.55}

Comment: you need to define mathematically what does "combining weights" mean. First give a formal description, then give an example. An example without a definition will lead to guessing, confusion and a lot of back and forth.

Comment: Explain that in each step. You are still giving an example, because you are not explaining *why* any of these values are chosen

Comment: I suspect the answer involves `3 < 5`, `5 - 3`, `3 - 2`, `1 < 5` and `5 - 1`

Comment: @Caleth, yes, that's exactly it. I'm hoping to get a general formulation or maybe if there is a mathematical definition for this.

Comment: @Caleth if you understood can you please properly explain? I still have no idea.

Comment: @bolov (with copies in a pair of queues) comparing the front elements, you pop the smaller, add it to the output (unless zero), and decrement the larger by that value. repeat until empty

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience. I have added a picture in my post above showing the result I want to get.

Comment: yeah... the picture doesn't add anything that the text doesn't already says.

Comment: @bolov I apologize for that. The reason to use "weights or ratios" is when the sum of vector_1 and vector_2 are not the same. In that case, both vectors will have the same ratios as shown in the second picture in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than dividing each weight by it's total, you can find the [LCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of your totals, and multiply, which keeps you in integer arithmetic

```
int total1 = std::accumulate(weights1.begin(), weights1.end(), 0);
int total2 = std::accumulate(weights2.begin(), weights2.end(), 0);
int lcm = std::lcm(total1, total2);
```

We want to do destructive things below, so we may as well do that to adjusted values

```
std::deque<int> working1;
std::transform(weights1.begin(), weights1.end(), std::back_inserter(working1), [=](int w){ return w * lcm / total1; });

std::deque<int> working2;
std::transform(weights2.begin(), weights2.end(), std::back_inserter(working2), [=](int w){ return w * lcm / total2; });
```

Comparing the front elements, you pop the smaller, add it to the output (unless zero), and decrement the larger by that value. Repeat that process until both copies are empty

```
std::vector<int> combined;

while (!working1.empty() && !working2.empty())
{
    int & top1 = working1.front();
    int & top2 = working2.front();
    if (top1 < top2)
    {
        if (top1 > 0) { combined.push_back(top1) }
        top2 -= top1;
        working1.pop_front();
    }
    else
    {
        if (top2 > 0) { combined.push_back(top2) }
        top1 -= top2;
        working2.pop_front();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!